# How to protect against simple web distributed viruses

Tags: virus, antivirus, internet

I work as a data recovery consultant and a surprisingly large number of my clients are individuals that caught a virus from **"The Internet"**.

A lot of people would browse *dodgy* websites, download all kinds of files and click on those big flashy DOWNLOAD buttons without hesitation. I always try to give some advice as to how to be more cautious in general and a more technical approach to use things like Add-Blocker, a good antivirus and up-to-date modern browser.

Is there any more advanced approach for non-technical users to better protect against mass-targeted internet viruses.

Answer (score 0):

Really, especially for non-technical people, that's a good list of things to be careful about.  I'd add "only accept virus warnings from the AV software that you have installed on your PC" and "be careful where you go".

IF you want to get more technical I'd add "don't install Flash or Java" but that can cause other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a secure browser which is updated, disable plugins and install an adblocker. For maximum security install a script blocker.

I recommend using uBlock where you can just make checkmarks on different malware lists. As it blocks all major ad networks, it also protects against hacked ad networks (which is not uncommon). For a script blocker I recommend uMatrix. It allows very fine grained control over what is loaded, so your white list does not need to allow too much. So you can i.e. white list the jquery of the website without white listing the ad scripts.